# yii parent child Clistview paging issue

Tags: php, yii

I am using Yii framework of php. My scenario is I've number of projects and all the projects have posts. For projects i used Clistview and in the 'itemView' of this control another page is specified named '_post'. In '_post' page again ClistView is specified for showing post details.

But the problem is when paging occur in post details Clistview of the projects and changing the page number of the one post detail to next page number, all the post detail clistview page number changes.

I have also specified post detail clistview 'id' but in no vain.

For Projects:

```
<?php
$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name . ' - Project Post Details';
echo '<div class="listViewBorder">';
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', 
              array(
                  'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
                  'id'=>'projectListView',
                  'itemView'=>'_post', // refers to the partial view
                  'enablePagination'=>true,
              ));
echo '</div><br />'
?>
```

For Post detail:

```
<?php
echo '<h2>Project: '. CHTML::encode($data->title).' </h2>';
echo '<div class="listViewBorder">';
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView',
              array(
                  'dataProvider'=>$this->CallProjectPosts($data->id),
                  'id'=>'postListView'.$data->id,
                  'itemView'=>'_postDetail',
                  'enablePagination'=>true,
              ));
echo '</div>'
?>
```

Comment: Show us the code for both views.

Comment: Edit your question rather then post in the comments...

Comment: +1, good question, i think you might have to make a custom pager for the inner clistviews, or maybe try and override yiilistview.js, or maybe do something different in your data provider for the inner clistview, not sure.

Comment: did you post this in the yii forum? Also check out this extension which might be helpful : http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/nestedsetbehavior/

Comment: Basically child CLISTVIEW paging calls the project controller action and in this action Projects page is displayed and so on. I also post this issue on yii forum but get no response till now

Comment: Still waisting time on this issue

Comment: what are the things that you have tried till now?

Comment: i tried child ClistView route property, give a try of renderPartial and replace the child ClistView with infinite scroll extension.But could not get the desire results till now. Any idea would be appreciate.

Comment: Can you put your controller code also? for both the views. I'm trying to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i finally got it working, it will work until you find a better solution.
**i'm assuming that project_id is a foreign key in your posts table.**
Which will generate(using gii) the necessary HAS_MANY relation in your project model, which in turn enables us to access the posts of a project easily, without calling the CallProjectPosts method.

So modify your Post view(_post.php):

```
<?php
echo '<h2>Project: '. CHTML::encode($data->title).' </h2>';
echo '<div class="listViewBorder">';

$relatedPosts=new CArrayDataProvider($data->posts, // this is where the HAS_MANY relation comes into play
        array(
            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>1, // whatever your size was
            )
        )
);
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView',
           array(
               'dataProvider'=>$relatedPosts,
               'id'=>'postListView'.$data->id,
               'itemView'=>'_postDetail',
               'enablePagination'=>true,
           ));
echo '</div>'
?>
```

For Project list :

```
<?php
$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name . ' - Project Post Details';
echo '<div class="listViewBorder">';
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', 
          array(
              'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
              'id'=>'projectListView',
              'itemView'=>'_post', // refers to the partial view
              'enablePagination'=>true,
              'ajaxUpdate'=>false
          )
);
echo '</div><br />'
?>
```

As you will see, i have disabled ajaxUpdate for the project list view, if it is enabled, then the solution will not work, so if your requirement is to display/update the project list also through ajax then this will not work, currently only the project posts are updated through ajax.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried to follow the MVC model. Basically "CallProjectPosts" method specified in the PostController which further calls the model method "getProjectPosts($id)" according to some criteria. And off course Project ClistView will also use ajax for paging at projects level. I think current situation is not handled in yii framework till now. If  I could not able to get the solution then at last i'll change the structure of the functionality.

Comment: Fair enough, but if the project model and post model is related, then project has that relation, and we can use that relation, with **additional criteria** specified. i Am new to this, so i'm not really sure that using that relation will violate mvc or not. Basically you don't need to call post model, it'll happen internally when using the relation. As for ajax, i believe that, if in the project view you are only displaying projects, then it's ok if you get the next page without ajax. Only posts will be through ajax. Similar to comments to questions/answers here in stack overflow..

Comment: ..questions are loaded without ajax, but comments are. Just sharing my thoughts :).

Comment: You can however move the relatedPosts dataProvider to the controller, and you can also use CActiveDataProvider instead of CArrayDataProvider.

Comment: Now i m thinking to change the structure of the functionality like instead of using two CListView, infinite scroller extension of yii framework will use. By the way thanks for your time DroidUser.

Comment: DroidUser, i used some different strategy for the time being. But i want to spend further time on this problem personally. Would you discuss with me either it is yii bug or something else (OR) why you add 'ajaxUpdate'=>false. It will be better if you come up with detail, so that we could reach on some conclusion.Thanks

Comment: had to do make ajaxUpdate false for the outer clistvew, coz when the inner clistview ajax update was being called, for some reason the outer clistview update was also happening, you can see this behavior in Firebug's console view, so i just disabled the outer view's ajax, and then only the inner clistview's ajax was being called. Now, i don't think it is a bug, there has to be some method, to update only the inner view through ajax. Changed my name here, btw. I have posted the replies in yii forum too, someone there might be able to help us figure this out.